# Why does Chef need so many attribute types?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

According to the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-types) (emphasis mine):

> The chef-client uses *six types of attributes* to determine
>   the value that is applied to a node during the chef-client run.

I have some Chef experience, but in several years, I have never encountered a use case that needed different attribute types.
Now, a colleague left this comment in a change I proposed:

> you are sure that this `default` overrides the `default` of the cookbook?
>   wouldn't `normal` be better for this case?

Of course I'm not sure. I'm rather confused.

**What use cases justify having this kind of complexity?** Why does Chef need so many attribute types?

Comment: This is not really a question for StackOverflow. If you would like to discuss Chef's design philosophy (and how it has changed over the years) you can find me on IRC, Slack, or post to the Chef Dev category on Discourse.

Answer (score 3):

All in all, Chef does not need it, it allows it for convenience.

I would recommend against the use of `normal` as attributes of this type are stored in the node object permanently where `default` and `overrides` are always computed at compile time. The order of precedence matters for this, an `override` will surclasse the `normal` which will surclasse the `default`. Scheme of this is available in the [doc](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) you linked to.

For the reason why there are so many different types, it's to allow one to define defaults in a cookbook, and then supersede them in a wrapper cookbook, in a role, in an environment or in a recipe without having to change the cookbook itself.

Example case: I wish to set an Apache server on 3 boxes, I'll start with a cookbook doing a minimal install of apache2 with a default `listen_port` attribute of 80.

For my general cases (2 nodes on 3) I wish to have Apache listening on port 800 instead of default 80, and add some extra configuration. I'll do a generic wrapper around the apache install to change the `listen_port` attribute to 800 and do the extra configuration.

For the third node I wish to have the same configuration, but make it listen on port 2053. To tackle this I can set the attribute on the node, or in a role or in another wrapper cookbook.

If at any time I wish to ensure a parameter I set won't be superseded by a wrapper or a role, I can get a level over it, using `override` instead of `default` in an attribute file of a wrapper cookbook makes clear I'm willing to override this value and don't have it supersede when the inclusion happens.

At the end of the day, for 99% of cases, sticking with `default` level should be enough, but the other levels are available when needed, for quick fix or debug purposes etc.

Answer (score 0):

See the last section of this answer I gave to a previous question:

[Using attributes in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057926/using-attributes-in-chef/31084488#31084488)

Copied here:

The problem with Chef Attributes is that they've grown organically and sprouted many options to try to help out users who painted themselves into a corner. In general you should never need to touch automatic, normal, force_default or force_override levels of attributes. You should also avoid setting attributes in recipe code. You should move setting attributes in recipes to attribute files. What this leaves is these places to set attributes:

in the initial -j argument (sets normal attributes, you should limit using this to setting the run_state, over using this is generally smell)
in the role file as default or override precedence levels (careful with this one though because roles are not versioned and if you touch these attributes a lot you will cause production issues)
in the cookbook attributes file as default or override precedence levels (this is where you should set most of your attributes)
in environment files as default or override precedence levels (can be useful for settings like DNS servers in a datacenter, although you can use roles and/or cookbooks for this as well)
You also can set attributes in recipes, but when you do that you invariably wind up getting your next lesson in the two-phase compile-converge parser that runs through the Chef Recipes. If you have recipes that need to communicate with each other its better to use the node.run_state which is just a hash that doesn't get written as node attributes. You can drop node.run_state[:foo] = 'bar' in one recipe and read it in another. You probably will see recipes that set attributes though so you should be aware of that.